# get average x months weekly in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to get the average of past 6 months weekly. I tried below query but not resulting correct because average for each week am getting same,

```
select s.*,avg(sales) over (partition by sku_id,

substring(dateweeknum,1,4),substring(dateweeknum,6, 2) ) as avg_sum 

from 

( 

Select sku_id,dateweeknum, 

Sum(sales_data) Sales 

From table

WHERE  dateval>=Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -6, 

dateval)), 0) 

Group By sku_id,dateweeknum 

) s
```

my data is like -
dateweeknum : 2020/01-04  ( it has format yr/mon-week)
dateval - 20200928 (yearmonthdate)

sample ex:

```
|sku_id | dateweeknum | dateval  | sales_data|
|-------:-------------: -------- : --------- |
| ab124 |  2021/06-01 |  20210603|  10       |
| ab124 |  2021/05-01 |  20210502|  20       |
| ab124 |  2021/06-01 |  20210606|  30       |
| ab123 |  2021/06-01 |  20210606|  30       |
```

expected result:

| week | year | sales | AvgSales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2021 | 60 | 2.3 |

```
--> (60 1st week sum)
--> (26 weeks ie 6 months)
--> 60/26 = 2.3
```

Actual i need to get like: Total sales/total no of weeks  (only ab124 in where condition)
but am not able to get correct avg. can anyone please suggest where am going wrong.

Comment: Sampel data (in a consumable format) and expected results, along with a clear explanation of the logic will help us help you.

Comment: @Larnu added them...  but i did add all data.. some data.. Actually average how we do..

Comment: How do you get 60 for your week's 1 sales? There are 90 sales in week 1. Or if we're talking about June there are 70 (which month you are looking at is unclear due to a month column). YOur expected results don't make sense.

Comment: sorry forgot to tell.. i need to consider only sku_id = ab124 @Larnu